# How to get all comments in a group filtered by author?

Tags: graphql, gitlab

I have the following query

```
{
    group(fullPath: "X") {
        issues {
            count
        }
        projects {
            nodes {
                    name
                    issues(sort: CREATED_DESC, state: opened ) {
                        count
                        edges {
                            node {
                                iid
                                title
                                description
                                notes {
                                    nodes {
                                        id
                                        body 
                                        author  {
                                            name 
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It gives me all comments to open issues in group "X". But how can I retrieve only those made by author with name "B"